# Creating a Carousel in Phaser.io

Tags: javascript, carousel, phaser-framework

I am trying to create a carousel type effect in Phaser for selecting a character, there are many tutorials on creating a standard Carousel (Website Slideshows etc) but I am trying to create a Carousel that can display up 3 options at once, (if there are 3 to display), which I am not sure if there's a name for this specific type of carousel as my google searches so far haven't turned up anything I can learn from.

I cannot work out the logic needed to shift each image into the next slot along when the next and previous functions are called.

```
this.scrollingOptionsMenu.ShowSelectedOption();
```

ShowSelectedOption(); is called in the update function of the theme select state, other than this and the Prev(), Next() functions are called on keyboard press left or right respectively other than this all code is in the below file.

I have included the code I have so far below ScrollingOptionsMenu() is called in my create function of the theme select state, the `options` parameter is an array of files (for now just the thumbnail of each theme) pulled from a json file.

With my own current attempt, the images don't see to move into their new slots and I get an "property of x undefined' which I understand and could limit it going over but I am not really sure if I'm going the 'right' way with this.

Any help appreciated,

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

```
function ScrollingOptionsMenu(game, x, y, options)
{
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.options = options;
  this.optionsCount = options.length;
  this.game = game;
  this.currentIndex = 0;

  this.leftImage = game.add.sprite(x , y, 'theme1_thumbail');
  this.centerImage = game.add.sprite(x, y, 'theme2_thumbail');
  this.rightImage = game.add.sprite(x , y, 'theme3_thumbail');

  this.ImageGroup = [this.leftImage, this.centerImage, this.rightImage];

  this.leftImage.anchor.setTo(0.5);
  this.centerImage.anchor.setTo(0.5);
  this.rightImage.anchor.setTo(0.5);

  this.leftImage.x = x - this.leftImage.width;
  this.rightImage.x = x + this.rightImage.width;

  this.leftImage.scale.setTo(0.5);
  this.rightImage.scale.setTo(0.5);
  //console.log(width);
  console.log(this.leftImage);
  console.log(this.centerImage);
  console.log(this.rightImage);
}

//Display currently centerImage Option
ScrollingOptionsMenu.prototype.ShowSelectedOption = function()
{
  if(this.currentIndex == 0)
  {
    //if we are at 0 then the left slot should be empty
    this.leftImage.loadTexture('transParent', 0);
    this.centerImage.loadTexture(this.options[this.currentIndex].thumbnail.name, 0);
    this.rightImage.loadTexture(this.options[this.currentIndex+1].thumbnail.name, 0);
  }
  else{
    //if currentIndex is above 0 then place
    this.leftImage.loadTexture(this.options[this.currentIndex-1].thumbnail.name, 0);
    this.centerImage.loadTexture(this.options[this.currentIndex].thumbnail.name, 0);
    this.rightImage.loadTexture(this.options[this.currentIndex+1].thumbnail.name, 0);
  }
}

ScrollingOptionsMenu.prototype.NextOption = function()
{
  this.ChangeIndex(1);
}

ScrollingOptionsMenu.prototype.PreviousOption = function()
{
  this.ChangeIndex(-1);
}

//returns the index of the currently centerImage option
ScrollingOptionsMenu.prototype.GetCurrentIndex = function()
{
  return this.currentIndex;
}


ScrollingOptionsMenu.prototype.ChangeIndex = function(index)
{
  var optionsLength = this.options.length-1;
  if(this.currentIndex + index < 0)
  {
    this.currentIndex = 0;
  }
  else if(this.currentIndex + index > optionsLength)
  {
    this.currentIndex = optionsLength;
  }else{
    this.currentIndex += index;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I setup for you this example showing one way to approach this problem:
https://codepen.io/ChrisGhenea/pen/WZGjLg/

First all available themes are added to an array so you can keep track of them. Each element needs to be initialized

```
//array of all available themes
var themes = [];
themes.push(game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'theme1'));
themes.push(game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'theme2'));
themes.push(game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'theme3'));
themes.push(game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'theme4'));
themes.push(game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'theme5'));
themes.push(game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'theme6'));

themes.forEach(function (item) {
  item.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
  item.x = game.width + 150;
  item.y = game.height / 2;
  item.inputEnabled = true;
  item.events.onInputDown.add(clickListener, this);
})
```

The you set the highlighted position (the one in the middle) and place the elements on the stage:

```
function setToPosition(prime) {
  themes[prime].x = game.width / 2;

  //check if there is another theme available to display on the right side; if yes then position it
  if (prime<(totalThemes-1)) {
    themes[prime + 1].x = game.width / 2 + 140;
    themes[prime + 1].scale.setTo(0.5,0.5);
  }

  //check if there is another theme available to display on the left side; if yes then position it
  if (prime > 0) {
    themes[prime - 1].x = game.width / 2 - 140;
    themes[prime - 1].scale.setTo(0.5,0.5);
  }
}
```

The animation happens on click; depending on which theme is clicked the list is moved left or right:

```
//move to next theme
function nextTheme() {
  //move prime left
  game.add.tween(themes[prime]).to( { x: xleft}, animationSpeed, null, true);
  game.add.tween(themes[prime].scale).to( { x: 0.5 , y: 0.5}, animationSpeed, null, true);
  //move right to prime
  if (prime < 5) {
    game.add.tween(themes[prime+1]).to( { x: xprime}, animationSpeed, null, true);
    game.add.tween(themes[prime+1].scale).to( { x: 1 , y: 1}, animationSpeed, null, true);
  }
  //move new to right
  if (prime < 4) {
    themes[prime+2].x = game.width + 150;
    themes[prime+2].scale.setTo(0.5,0.5);
    game.add.tween(themes[prime+2]).to( { x: xright}, animationSpeed, null, true);
  }
  //move left out
  if (prime>0) {
    //themes[prime+1].x = -150;
    themes[prime-1].scale.setTo(0.5,0.5);
    game.add.tween(themes[prime-1]).to( { x: -150}, animationSpeed, null, true);
  }
  prime++;

}

//move to previous theme
function previousTheme() {
  //move prime left
  game.add.tween(themes[prime]).to( { x: xright}, animationSpeed, null, true);
  game.add.tween(themes[prime].scale).to( { x: 0.5 , y: 0.5}, animationSpeed, null, true);
  //move left to prime
  if (prime > 0 ) {
    game.add.tween(themes[prime-1]).to( { x: xprime}, animationSpeed, null, true);
    game.add.tween(themes[prime-1].scale).to( { x: 1 , y: 1}, animationSpeed, null, true);
  }
  //move new to left
  if (prime > 1) {
    themes[prime-2].x = - 150;
    themes[prime-2].scale.setTo(0.5,0.5);
    game.add.tween(themes[prime-2]).to( { x: xleft}, animationSpeed, null, true);
  }
  //move right out
  if (prime < (totalThemes-1)) {
    //themes[prime+1].x = -150;
    themes[prime+1].scale.setTo(0.5,0.5);
    game.add.tween(themes[prime+1]).to( { x: game.width + 150}, animationSpeed, null, true);
  }
  prime--;
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris, 

Firstly thanks very much for your help, your code makes a lot of sense to me, but I seem to have run into the same problem with your code as I did my own that is "Cannot set property 'x' of undefined" in the nextTheme function. 

Specifically this.optionsArray[this.currentIndex + 2].x = game.width + 150;

I think I understand this is telling me it can't set the property of an object that doesnt exist (makes sense) any idea how do I fix this? Is it because I only have 3 options currently where as your example used 5?

Comment: I have also uploaded a demo at https://grim-.github.io/ so you can see for yourself.

Comment: Looking more at it my problem seems to be with the hard coded values in the IF statements `if (this.currentIndex < 4) `  `if (this.currentIndex < 5) { ` 

I believe it may have to be changed to use the optionsArray.Length and subtract -1 or -2? 

Apologies for the multiple comments, would have edited the first if I could have.